Math in Hamiltonian of the hyperquantization of EM field
1. Background: I encounter this when looking into the hyperquantization of EM field.
We have the secondly quantized field as below:
$$\hat{E}^{(+)}(t)=\mathscr{E} e^{-iwt+i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}\hat{a}=\left(\hat{E}^{(-)}\right)^\dagger \tag{1.1}$$
If we calculate the energy of the electric field in classical treatment, shown as below:
$$Enegry=\int d\vec{r} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_0E^2\tag{1.2} + Magnetic\_term$$
and we operationalize the electric field(Eq 1.3):
$$E=\hat{E}^{(+)}+\hat{E}^{(-)}\tag{1.3}$$
The integral yields a Hamiltonian operator:
$$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2} hw(\hat{a}\hat{a}^\dagger+\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a})  \tag{1.4}$$
2. Problem
We obtain Eq 1.4 with a extra approximation that the integral spatial region is big enough,
thus $\int d\vec{r}\hat{a}\hat{a} e^{-2iwt+2i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}} $ vanishes.
So what if the approximation fail when the volume is small?

No such approximation is needed, the time-dependent terms are cancelled between the electric- and magnetic-field terms. See chapter 4 of Loudon.
